# API face recognization doesn't work with PHP 5

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a facial recognization system, i use the KeyLemon API , i copied the file in EasyPHP (the last version so PHP 5) and i have a lot of errors when i want to use the function of the API .

```
//ssl certificate
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, Server_Connection::SSL_VERIFYPEER);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, Server_Connection::SSL_VERIFYHOST);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  dirname(__FILE__).'/CA/KL_GlobalSignOrganizationValidationCA-G2.crt');
```

I also try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2, Server_Connection::SSL_VERIFYHOST); but i get the still error : Warning: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 4 given`

And in index.php :

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$gender in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\src\index.php on line 35
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$age in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\src\index.php on line 36
```

The API has to work, i didn't touch anuthing, i guess it's because of the version of PHP .

index.php

```
try{
    //images can be given as an url array or data directly. If sending a path, add the prefix @
    $images_url = array('http://www.keylemon.com/images/saas/group.jpg');
    $images_data = array(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/penelope.jpg'), '@'.__DIR__.'/alba.jpg');

    //detect face(s) in the image and request gender+age (properties)
    $properties = true;
    $res_detect = $kl_api->detect_faces($images_url, $images_data, $properties);

    //check if some errors
    if($res_detect->errors){
        foreach($res_detect->errors as $error){
            print $error->error_id.':'.$error->message;
        }
    }

    //print faces detected
    if($res_detect->faces){
        foreach($res_detect->faces as $face){
            print $face->face_id.': position:'.$face->x.','.$face->y.', size:'.$face->w.'x'.$face->h.'<br/>';
            print 'Gender : '.$face->gender;
            print 'Age : '.$face->age;
        }
    }
}
catch (KL_Exception $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

In the page :

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 4 given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\src\server_connection.php on line 188
711be4c4-4741-4756-866e-477045c33847: position:268,288, size:300x300
Gender : femaleAge : 18ea840197-4c6d-4c4a-883b-fd18d69a6aba: position:242,882, size:19x19

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$gender in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\src\index.php on line 35
Gender :
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$age in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\src\index.php on line 36
Age : f0b7dcef-2918-4b20-a08f-2b5402810baf: position:63,73, size:100x100
Gender : femaleAge : 1940cc8492-ab6d-488d-a06e-081f1cc22c62: position:485,131, size:136x136
Gender : maleAge : 186d32a3a9-f822-4ec2-a372-c1cda4c6ccae: position:144,265, size:134x134
Gender : femaleAge : 15b66a6e1a-5c3e-4270-90e7-d92ca951b0f8: position:715,234, size:125x125
Gender : femaleAge : 192897a4f1-5406-4d85-bdda-008251a137a0: position:840,168, size:117x117
Gender : maleAge : 28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no errors, there are notices and warnings.

In `index.php`, for example, notices say that you are trying to access properties which are not defined in object (`$face->gender` and `$face->age`). You should look at API documentation more carefully.

The warning appears because you pass 4 parameters to `curl_setopt` function which expects **exactly 3** parameters.